# Can we have both Direct X9 and 11 on the same Windows 7 system?

Tags: windows-7, directx

I'm already having DirectX 11 but some games and software have an option to install DirectX 9 by force which I can't stop. Is there any harm if I install game or software along with DX9 ?

Answer (score 4):

DX9 is a subset of DX11 so effectively you already have DX9 installed on your system.

The installers should detect this and not actually install anything.

If you are particularly concerned though, run the DX11 installer again after the DX9 one. In the unlikely event of there being any problems this should correct them.

Comment: DirectX 9 runtimes are updated frequently, a stock Windows 7 install is unlikely to have these runtimes ( eg: the recent runtime update was in Feb 2010).

Comment: I think I've DX 11 but they are not detecting, but i'm not confirm. because they doesn't give any message about this

Comment: I agree installers _should_ detect this. But some don't. I had the same and now I'm concerned my installation is compromised.

Answer (score 3):

No, there won't be any problems.

Comment: then which directx will open from dxdiag.exe? 11 or 9

Comment: One pointing to DX11